# Passing array to jquery arguments

Tags: jquery

I want the result of my alert become `a[one:1]..b[four:4]..` here is my code

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: {
    four: 4,
    five: 5,
    six: 6
  }
};
$.each(myObject, function(a, b) {
  alert(a + b);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$.each(myObject, function(a, b) {
  $.each(b, function(c, d) {
    alert(a + "["+c+":"+d+"]" );
  })
})
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/L2bfvrot/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but can is there any way that i can alert a[one:1] only and so on.

Comment: you wanna to display first one only ? @NelsonTan

Comment: i want to alert every one set of an array in a and b. for example. alert(a[one:1]),alert(a[two:2])......